# If condition in extending a class

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

In an Android app. I have a requirement where I have my `HomeActivity` (having 18000 lines of code) and if my device supports `ARCore`, I want `HomeActivity` to extend with `ARBaseACtivity` and if device doesn't supports `ARCore` then I need it to extend with `NonARBaseActivity`.

I am checking this condition in splash screen.

Now, there is a way that first comes is that I make two activities, same a copy of `HomeActivity` but I need to know is there any better way to do that. Because I don't want to copy every time I do any change in one of the `HomeActivity`.

Comment: You need to create 2 classes if they have a different behaviour. But try to mutualize all common code in an inherited class

Answer (score 6):

The technical answer is: **not** possible.

In Java, your inheritance structure is fixed. It is simply not possible to have one class C extend class A in one context, and class B in another context. When you want to do that, you would end up having two classes, C1 and C2.

The real answer of course is: you have to step back and clearly *architect* your whole solution. Alone the 18K lines in *one* whatever is an indication that something is seriously wrong here. One could mention the good old [FCoI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle, but then: 18K lines of code means a lot of code and features. It is simply impossible to give you proper guidance in a single answer on stackoverflow.

So, opinionated: you should step back, and identify some (architecture) experts to talk to. Then sit down with them (probably for hours, even days), and look at what you have got, and where you want to get to. Then work together on path there. Anything else is nothing but putting band-aids on symptoms. Sure, nothing will break when you don't do that. But each step forward will simply add *mess* to *mess*, making each step more expensive. Sooner or later, changing your monolith will become close to impossible, and everybody will ask to "throw it away, and start from scratch".

Comment: Yes you are somewhere right, from starting i didn't followed any architecture and now its been 1.5 years , the requirements were like that i have to do everything in one activity and now its looking mess. I have to follow some architecture and do some optimisations. Anyway thanks for answering !!

Answer (score 2):

As complement to the excellent answer of GhostCat, I will give you a very important hint in OOP : to enhance **at runtime** the behavior of an object, the decorator pattern is often a way to consider.

Here `HomeActivity` appears as the element to decorate and `ARBaseACtivity` and `NonARBaseActivity` appears as decorator for that.
You should define a `MyActivity` interface that is the base class for both decorated and decorator objects.

So things are not simple because you will have to refactor many code lines but it will make your design more flexible and with classes that have consistent responsibilities instead of having a god object as activity !

Finally in the splash screen you could define a method that returns an activity  decorating the `HomeActivity` according to the client material detected :

```
public MyActivity computeHomeActivity(){

    HomeActivity activity = new HomeActivity();

    if (isSupportARCore()){
       return new ARBaseACtivity(activity);
    }
    return new NonARBaseActivity(activity);

}
```

Comment: He there ... looking into old stuff here ... great to see how good you are doing ;-)

Comment: Hello you ! I see that you "hunt"/"clean" unaccepted question ! Thanks for your good words ! By the way I tried to improve the post ! Those days I worked with Python (I never did so far). I know that you practice it. Interesting language. But well the duck typing annoys me a little.

Comment: Yes, the static typing as by Java or kotlin works better for me, too!